# Powershell: FCIV script error: "Cannot find path because it does not exist"

Tags: powershell, fciv

I am new to PowerShell, so I may have missed something simple. I am trying to run a file checksum for `Start-PsFCIV`, [outlined here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-File-Checksum-e57dcd67).

My attempt is below, where I have also tried excluding the `-Path` parameter, as well as using relative/absolute paths.

```
PS C:\Users\Lucas\Downloads> Start-PsFCIV -Path C:\Users\Lucas\Downloads\DXSDK_Jun10.exe -HashAlgorithm SHA1
Set-Location : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Lucas\Downloads\DXSDK_Jun10.exe' because it does not exist.
At C:\Scripts\PsFCIV_2.5.ps1:227 char:3
+         Set-Location -LiteralPath $path
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Lucas\Downloads\DXSDK_Jun10.exe:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'LiteralPath' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Scripts\PsFCIV_2.5.ps1:280 char:32
+         if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $XML)) {return New-Object PsFCIV.FCIV}
+                                      ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

__fromxml : Input XML file is not valid FCIV XML file.
At C:\Scripts\PsFCIV_2.5.ps1:511 char:9
+     $sum = __fromxml $xml
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,__fromxml

Exception setting "VerboseForegroundColor": "Cannot convert value "-1" to type "System.Windows.Media.Color". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.ConsoleColor' to 'System.Windows.Media.Color'.""
At C:\Scripts\PsFCIV_2.5.ps1:607 char:4
+             $host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Scripts\PsFCIV_2.5.ps1:612 char:4
+             $sum.FILE_ENTRY.Add($entry)
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception setting "VerboseForegroundColor": "Cannot convert value "-1" to type "System.Windows.Media.Color". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.ConsoleColor' to 'System.Windows.Media.Color'.""
At C:\Scripts\PsFCIV_2.5.ps1:607 char:4
+             $host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

How can I get this command to work? I could not find any solutions or similar problems after ~15 min search.

Answer (score 0):

The first exception you get is thrown by `Set-Location` cmdlet that for some reason is used in the Start-PsFCIV script. Set-Location expects a folder as its `-LiteralPath` argument but you pass it a file instead.

As per ["Useful Examples" on the PsFCIV webpage](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-File-Checksum-e57dcd67) the solution is to use `-Include` argument. Example:

```
Start-PsFCIV -Path C:\tmp -Include InstallPackage.msi -XML DB.XML -HashAlgorithm SHA512
# Checks only InstallPackage.msi file in C:\tmp folder by using SHA512 hash algorithm.
```